# How does one write a big $\oplus$ sign?

Tags: math-mode

How can I write a big `$\oplus$` sign? I've been experimenting with lots of different things like `$Oplus$`, but nothing is working.

Comment: Are you talking about `\displaystyle\oplus`? Or `\bigoplus`?

Comment: @Sigur- Thanks, that answers my question!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{relsize}

\begin{document}
$\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\oplus}}}$
\end{document}
```