# How can I lighten the following spaghetti definitions (symbols in $\Box$ and $\Diamond$)?

Tags: pdftex, math-operators, logic

I am trying to insert symbols into $\Box$ and $\Diamond$.

I do it in the following way.

First I define commands for blank operators for future and past:

```
\newcommand{\pastDiamond}
{
  \text{\raisebox{-.37em}{
     \topinset{$\rule{.3em}{.8pt}$}
     {$\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger\Diamond}}}$}
     {3.8pt}
     {-4pt}}
  }
}%


\newcommand{\futureDiamond}
{
 \text{\raisebox{-.37em}{
    \topinset{$\rule{.3em}{.8pt}$}
    {$\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger\Diamond}}}$}
    {3.8pt}
    {4pt}}
 }
}%


\newcommand{\pastBox}
 {
  \text{\raisebox{-.19em}{
      \topinset{$\rule{.25em}{.8pt}$}
      {$\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger\Box}}}$}
      {4.5pt}
      {-3.5pt}}
  }
}%


\newcommand{\futureBox}
{
  \text{\raisebox{-.19em}{
      \topinset{$\rule{.25em}{.8pt}$}
      {$\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger\Box}}}$}
      {4.5pt}
      {3.5pt}}
  }
}%
```

Then I define command to superimpose operators with symbols:

```
\makeatletter
  \newcommand{\superimpose}[2]
              {%
                {\ooalign{$#1\@firstoftwo#2$\cr\hfil$#1\@secondoftwo#2$\hfil\cr}}
              }
  \makeatother
```

Then I use the aboce commands to insert the symbols **F**, **S** and **f** inside the operators:

```
  \newcommand{\FFutureDiamond}{\!\!\!\!\mathpalette\superimpose{{\futureDiamond}{{\mathsmaller{F}}}}}
  \newcommand{\FPastDiamond}{\!\!\!\!\mathpalette\superimpose{{\pastDiamond}{{\mathsmaller{F}}}}}
  \newcommand{\SFutureDiamond}{\!\!\!\!\mathpalette\superimpose{{\futureDiamond}{{\mathsmaller{S}}}}}
  \newcommand{\SPastDiamond}{\!\!\!\!\mathpalette\superimpose{{\pastDiamond}{{\mathsmaller{S}}}}}
  \newcommand{\fFutureDiamond}{\!\!\!\!\mathpalette\superimpose{{\futureDiamond}{\mathsmaller{f}}}}
  \newcommand{\fPastDiamond}{\!\!\!\!\mathpalette\superimpose{{\pastDiamond}{\mathsmaller{f}}}}
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \newcommand{\FFutureBox}{\!\!\!\!\mathpalette\superimpose{{\futureBox}{{\mathsmaller{F}}}}}
  \newcommand{\FPastBox}{\!\!\!\!\mathpalette\superimpose{{\pastBox}{{\mathsmaller{F}}}}}
  \newcommand{\SFutureBox}{\!\!\!\!\mathpalette\superimpose{{\futureBox}{{\mathsmaller{S}}}}}
  \newcommand{\SPastBox}{\!\!\!\!\mathpalette\superimpose{{\pastBox}{{\mathsmaller{S}}}}}
  \newcommand{\fFutureBox}{\!\!\!\!\mathpalette\superimpose{{\futureBox}{\mathsmaller{f}}}}
  \newcommand{\fPastBox}{\!\!\!\!\mathpalette\superimpose{{\pastBox}{\mathsmaller{f}}}}
```

What I have received is the following:

[image: Result]

> But I suspect I do it in a wrong way. I am sure It must be very heavy weight code to compile.

> May I receive the same result in more correct way, with some kind of more lighter code?

Comment: Looks pretty reasonable, but I didn't figure out what you use the mathpallete for.  There's also [spacing - Large negative spaces - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67912/large-negative-spaces)

Comment: Side note, repeated/nested \mathlarger is actually quite commonly seen around here e.g. [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/303313) [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39181) [3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/220028) [4](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/303600) [5](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/488325) so it should be okay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possibly better approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\BigBox}{\scalebox{1.7}{$\m@th\Box$}}
\newcommand{\BigDiamond}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{\BigBox}}
\newcommand{\PF}[3]{\mathord{% ensure math mode
  \vphantom{#1}%
  \ooalign{$\m@th\vcenter{\hbox{#1}}$\cr#2\cr\hidewidth$\m@th\mathop{#3}$\hidewidth\cr}%
}}
\newcommand{\Past}{$\m@th\mskip2mu\vcenter{\hrule width 0.25em height 0.2ex}$\hidewidth}
\newcommand{\Future}{\hidewidth$\m@th\vcenter{\hrule width 0.25em height 0.2ex}\,$}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\PF{\BigBox}{\Past}{S}$
$\PF{\BigBox}{\Past}{F}$
$\PF{\BigBox}{\Past}{f}$

$\PF{\BigBox}{\Future}{S}$
$\PF{\BigBox}{\Future}{F}$
$\PF{\BigBox}{\Future}{f}$

$\PF{\BigDiamond}{\Past}{S}$
$\PF{\BigDiamond}{\Past}{F}$
$\PF{\BigDiamond}{\Past}{f}$

$\PF{\BigDiamond}{\Future}{S}$
$\PF{\BigDiamond}{\Future}{F}$
$\PF{\BigDiamond}{\Future}{f}$

\end{document}
```

This assumes you don't want to use these symbols in subscripts or superscripts. You may want to define commands instead of using `\PF` directly.

[image]

Comment: Briliant!
Thank you a lot!